# Space of Continuous functions from Hilbert Cube is separable

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to prove that $C([0,1]^\mathbb{N})$, the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ into a scalar field, is separable.
I am able to prove that $C([0,1])$ is separable using Stone Weierstrass, but I am not sure how to use this to get that $C([0,1]^\mathbb{N})$ is also separable.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $H$ the Hilbert cube.

Consider the space of functions that depends on only finitely many coordinates, i.e.

$S:=\{f \in C(H)| \exists F \subset \mathbb{N}: |F|<\infty \forall x, y \in H \text{ we have } (\forall k \notin F x_k=y_k) \text{ implies } f(x)=f(y)\}$.

This is clearly an algebra.  It contains the constants, and separates points because any two points that are distinct must differ in some coordinate.  Thus $S$ is dense in $C(H)$ and so it suffices to show that $S$ is separable.

We can write $S=\cup_N S_N$ where $S_N$ is the set of functions depending on only the coordinates $1, \dots, N$.  Thus, $S$ is a union of subspaces of $C(H)$ that are separable in their own relative metrics. (Why are the $S_N$ separable?  Because it's "like" $C([0, 1]^N)$.  Can you make this precise?)  Thus $S$ is itself separable because the countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: I am still struggling to see why each $S_N$ is separable. If each $S_N$ is "like" $C([0,1]^\mathbb{N})$, I am not sure how this would show separability of $S_N$ because at this point we haven't proved that $C([0,1]^\mathbb{N})$ is separable yet. I must be missing what you are hinting at. Could you please give me a further hint?

Comment: @user224949 It seems that I forgot some latex symbols.  I mean finite $N$, not $\mathbb{N}$, when I discuss $S_N$.  The separability of these follows from Stone Weierstrass.